# How do I program a rf transmitter for a piece of equipment

Tags: controller

I have a rf transmitter and receiver for a stump grinder. It allows me to grind stumps from a safe distance. The remote got ran over on a job site. The company wants $3000 for a new remote. I have a bachelors in computer science but it’s been about three years. I feel like I could program the remote but want to get an idea of how hard it would be before I invest my time and any information on where to start, YouTube links, or a general outline of the process would be helpful.

It’s controls:
-steering stump grinder (L/R, F/B)
-operating the head (engage blade, move head L/R/Up/Down
-on/off switch

I’ve tried basic research into programming rf transmitter and reciever